# google colaboratory doesn't gives good accuracy compare to local machine

Tags: google-colaboratory

i have a model it gives good accuracy in local machine but when it comes to google colaboratory it doesn't gives good accuracy.Is there any specific way to train a model in google colaboratory for text/vision models

Answer (score 0):

I also got same situation when simulating quantum physics, my local code run nicely, but when moved to colaboratory, some thing messed up. I stepped into my code and found the reason is that numpy on Colab some times gives different results, such as using numpy to compute eigen vector and eigen values. The numpy method`numpy.linalg.eigh(H)`  will yield good eigen values, but the eigen vectors are different from local mechine a lot, such may due to a phase different. That's very annoying.